# How to skip changelog on new databases?

Tags: liquibase

I have a liquibase. Changelog with several changesets. All of them are already persisted to database.
The bug in one of changesets is revealed.
I want to skip this particular changeset(I cannot fix the bug because in order to fix it i need to create several new changesets(old one cannot be edited) )

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but if you want a changeSet to be skipped, you can use `<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">` and put the inside a condition that you know will fail. This way this particular changeset won't be executed, but all the others will.

Also, already executed changesets **can** be edited (however, it's a bad practice to do so). You may edit it and add `<validCheckSum>ANY (or a new check sum)</validCheckSum>` at the beginning of `changeSet`.